# Remote debugging Chromebook

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromebook

I read [this awesome technique](http://blog.chromium.org/2011/05/remote-debugging-with-chrome-developer.html) about remote debugging a Chrome browser instance from another Chrome browser instance,

I am wondering if it's possible to do this with a Chromebook.

How can I debug a Chromebook remotely the same way I can [debug Chrome on Android](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging)?

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: Because I needed to debug a chrome extension that behaved differently on desktop and chromebook. Eventually I discovered that it is due to the fact that on windows the file names are not case sensitive (unlike the linux-based chromebook), so the Javascript files were not being loaded properly.

Comment: Couldn't you have used the inspector tools on the Chromebook itself?

Comment: Yes, eventually I did but it wasn't as smooth as debugging locally (with file editing, etc.)

Comment: Oh, did you know there are decent text editors and other development tools available on Chromebooks?

Comment: Yeah but my Chromebook is kinda crappy and I rather use my big dual screen monitor and ergonomic keyboard and mouse that is attached to my main machine instead of doing the actual code editing on the Chromebook. I like to debug Chrome remotely. Even IE allows remote debugging using Chrome dev tools: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2015/04/02/introducing-the-ie-diagnostics-adapter-for-third-party-developer-tools.aspx The choice of IDE can be quite objective. I don't want to change my IDE for every target device.